# Flutter build fails with 'this and base files have different roots' error

Tags: flutter, mobile-application, flutter-build, flutter-debug

flutter build fails
Could not create task ':flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle:generateDebugUnitTestConfig'.
this and base files have different roots: D:\untitled\build\flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle and C:\Users\RK\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle-2.0.15\android.

Could not create task ':flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle:generateDebugUnitTestConfig'.
this and base files have different roots: D:\untitled\build\flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle and C:\Users\RK\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle-2.0.15\android.

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to run: `flutter clean`
2. Check and sync gradle files with project
3. Sometimes helps to update the gradle version to 7.0.3 (from 7.0.0)

Comment: actually I already have latest version of gradle, I tried flutter clean as well, the AP runs in chrome edge etc, but when on emulator or real devce , the sync of gradle gives this error      flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle:generateDebugUnitTestConfig'. this and base files have different roots: D:\untitled\build\flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle and C:\Users\RK\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle-2.0.15\android.

Answer (score 0):

inside the android not the root directory I did:
run flutter clean
flutter upgrade
flutter pub get
flutter pub update